# Bookmarklet to search input text and select from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

i wanted to create Bookmarklet which i key-in input, then it search and select from dropdown list in webpage.

i have some code below, but it not working.
thanks.

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dtgLot" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dtgLot\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dtgLot" style="width:200px;">


<option selected="selected" value=""></option>
    <option value="!E625163.05">!E625163.05</option>
    <option value="1E001196">1E001196</option>
    <option value="1E001242.08">1E001242.08</option>
    <option value="1E001492.03">1E001492.03</option>
    <option value="1E001493.02">1E001493.02</option>
</select>
```

Bookmarklet code

```
javascript:document.getElementsByName("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dtgLot")[0].value = 1E001196;document.getElementsByName("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dtgLot")[0].onchange();
```

Comment: anymore suggestion or idea guys?

Comment: any idea? i am clueless.

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript:document.querySelector(`select[name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1"] option[value="${prompt('Search value:')}"]`).value = true
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.